# How to properly submit form from a UL LI element?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have the following js function that submits my HTML postform - in the HTML ul below I can submit the form correctly using either the "input", "button", or "href" li elements. What is the preferred method or best practice way, why should I choose one method over the other? Eventually the sidebar will have several choices for the user to select from.

Note: I want the clickable sidebar elements to look like selectable text not a button, class="astext" performs this with CSS. I am only targeting the latest browsers.

```js
   <script type="text/javascript">
    function submitForm(queryType) {

        // set the hidden input's query type value
        $('#db_query').val(queryType);

        // submit the form.
        $('#post_form').submit();

    }
    </script>
```

```html
<body>
  
    <form method="POST" name="postform" id="post_form" action="process.php">
        <input name="display" id="display_id" type="hidden" value="north" />
        <input name="query" id="db_query" type="hidden" value="all" />
    </form>
  
    <aside id="sidebar">
          <h3>Schedule selection items here...</h3>
          <!-- I can use "input", or "button", or "href" below to submit the form, what is the correct way or does it really matter? -->
          <!-- they are all clear to me and seem to be maintainable? -->

          <ul>
             <li><input onclick="submitForm('tomorrow');" type="submit" name="schedule" class="astext" value="Select Tomorrow" /></li>
             <li><button onclick="submitForm('recent');" type="submit" name="schedule" class="astext">Select Recent</button></li>
             <li><a href="#" onclick="submitForm('all');" class="astext">Select All</a></li>
          </ul>
    
    </aside>
  
</body>
```

Comment: in your context, it does not matter at all. because you are invoking a submit via javascript anyways.

Comment: Better practice to use a button for javascript-submitted forms, IMO...

Comment: Do I even need the type="submit" for input or button?

Comment: buttons are default to submit, unless you specify it's type attribute as button. But if a button is not placed inside a form tag, then you don't need to worry about specifying the type attribute

Comment: Yes, you need the `type="submit"`.  The default type for [input](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type.asp) is text, and the default type for [button](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_type.asp) depends on the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're submitting the form within JavaScript so the browser doesn't really care which element you hook the submit function to.
For clarity purposes, I would go with either `<a>` or `<button>` (since `<input>`s are usually placed within `<form>` tags), and the exact choice would depend on whether I want to use a link to send the form or a button (even though with CSS you can style an `<a>` element like a button, and a `<button>` element like a hyperlink).

Comment: I have decided to go with the <a> for this particular case because I want the selection to look like clickable text rather than a button. If I wanted the selection to look like a button I would go with the <button>.

Answer (score 2):

Since you want it to "look like selectable text" anyway, there is no need to use any special element. You can simply hook it to the <li> itself:

```
<ul>
    <li onclick="submitForm('tomorrow');">Select Tomorrow</li>
    <li onclick="submitForm('recent');">Select Recent</li>
    <li onclick="submitForm('all');">Select All</li>
</ul>
```

There should not be any accessibility issues, however if you wanted to really make sure for the options to be accessible via keyboard, then input-elements are your safest bet.

Comment: thanks for this information I didn't think about this initially as another option and I may consider this. Also did not take into account keyboard accessible.